# Understanding the Debug implementation for Vec<T>

Tags: reference, rust, dereference

Trying to implement the `Debug` trait for a custom type I stumbled upon the implementation for `Vec<T>`. I have difficulties understanding how it works.

The implementation goes like this:

```
impl<T: fmt::Debug> fmt::Debug for Vec<T> {
    fn fmt(&self, f: &mut fmt::Formatter) -> fmt::Result {
        fmt::Debug::fmt(&**self, f)
    }
}
```

I understand it calls the `fmt` implementation for some other type. What I cannot understand is what type it is. I've tried to figure it out with the help of [another question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28519997/what-are-rusts-exact-auto-dereferencing-rules), and searching among the [implementations of `Debug`](http://file:///home/toro2k/stuff/opt/rust/share/doc/rust/html/std/fmt/trait.Debug.html) for something that looks appropriate (maybe something like `&[T]`), but with no success.

What is the exact meaning of `&**self` in this context? What implementation of `Debug` is being called?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In cases like this, I find it useful to make the compiler tell you what the type is. Just cause a type error and let the compiler diagnostics do it for you. The easiest way is to try to assign your item to something of type `()`:

```
fn main() {
    let v = &vec![1,2,3];
    let () = v;
    let () = &**v;
}
```

The errors are:

```
<anon>:3:9: 3:11 error: mismatched types:
 expected `&collections::vec::Vec<_>`,
    found `()`
(expected &-ptr,
    found ()) [E0308]
<anon>:3     let () = v;
                 ^~
<anon>:4:9: 4:11 error: mismatched types:
 expected `&[_]`,
    found `()`
(expected &-ptr,
    found ()) [E0308]
<anon>:4     let () = &**v;
                 ^~
```

Thus `v` is a `&collections::vec::Vec<_>` and `&**v` is a `&[_]`.

More detailed, `Vec` has this:

```
impl<T> Deref for Vec<T> {
    type Target = [T];
    // ...
}
```

So, we dereference once to go from `&Vec<T>` to a `Vec<T>`, dereference *again* to get a `[T]`, and then reference once to get a `&[T]`.

`[T]` has this:

```
impl<T> Debug for [T] {
    fn fmt(&self, ...) ...;
}
```

<s>However, when searching for an appropriate method to call, Rust will [automatically attempt to dereference](https://stackoverflow.com/q/28519997/155423) the target. That means we can find the method on `[T]` from a `&[T]`.</s>

As [corrected by Francis Gagné](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30261815/understanding-the-debug-implementation-for-vect/30261979?noredirect=1#comment48641271_30261979), `Debug::fmt` takes `&self`, so directly calling it with a `&[T]` finds the matching implementation. No need for any automatic referencing or dereferencing.

Comment: Thank you! I just miss one thing: I've found an implementation for `[T]` but not for `&[T]`, is it the latter to get called? Why?

Comment: @toro2k I added a bit more about that. Let me know if it helps!

Comment: I don't think there's any auto-dereferencing (or auto-referencing), because `fmt::Debug::fmt()` takes `self` by reference, i.e. it expects a `&[T]`, and it's given a `&[T]`.